# How can I override "after_sign_up_path_for" in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I am building a Rails application (using **ActiveAdmin** and **Devise**) and I am trying to override the **after_sign_up_path_for** to change the redirection after signing up.
I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)) from devise but my **RegistrationsController** is never called. I guess it might work a little bit differently with ActiveAdmin.

I also tried other solution I found on stack overflow without any luck.

**Here is my routes**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_config = ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  devise_config[:controllers][:omniauth_callbacks] = 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
  devise_config[:controllers][:registrations] = 'registrations'
  devise_for :users, devise_config

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  # other routes
end
```

**And my RegistrationsController**: (which is never called)

```
class RegistrationsController < ActiveAdmin::Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def sign_up(_resource_name, _resource)
    true
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(_resource)
    root_url
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help !

**My project**:

- Rails 4.2.6
- ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre2
- Devise 3.5.9

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin don't use your RegistrationsController and can't use them. You can define that method on your ApplicationController or you can do it this way:

```
# conig/initializer/active_admin.rb
ActiveAdmin::Devise::RegistrationsController.class_eval do
  def after_sign_up_path_for(_resource)
    root_url
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! 
I already try this but it didn't work either in active_admin.rb or in ApplicationController. I am still redirected to /admin/login page :(