# Devise :: Trouble registering with custom fields to sign_up form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration

I am building a Rails application and I have some issues while **registering** users with **Devise** (and ActiveAdmin).
To the original sign_up form, I added a custom username field and this one cause me troubles: sometime user can register other time it doesn’t (a validation error is raised for the username permitted params whereas I specified in controller I was allowing it).

**Here is my user model**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :username,
            presence: true,
            uniqueness: {
              case_sensitive: false,
              scope: :provider
            },
            if: proc { |u| u.new_record? || u.changed? }

  # other stuff here
end
```

**Here is what I have set up in my controller:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
end
```

When the validation error is raised for username, I guess it’s because this code is never called and this is where I’m stuck.

In development, I have to kill all ruby processes and then it work again for 3 or 4 registrations and then raise error again.

So what's could be wrong with my code ???

Thanks for your help !

**Edit**:
I discovered when I make a modification to my ruby code it stop working (unit tests stop passing). Could it be a cache issue ?

**Edit 2**: 
here are my development logs for sign_up when it fails

```
14:19:05 web.1         | [INFO ] POST    "/admin"  for 127.0.0.1  at 2016-05-14 14:19:05 +0200
14:19:05 web.1         | [DEBUG]   Setting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings`  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
14:19:05 web.1         | [DEBUG]   Setting::Translation Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `setting_translations`.* FROM `setting_translations` WHERE `setting_translations`.`setting_id` = 1
14:19:05 web.1         | [DEBUG]   Category Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`name` = 'LegalNotice' LIMIT 1
14:19:05 web.1         | [DEBUG]   Menu Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `menus`.* FROM `menus` WHERE `menus`.`id` IN (8)
14:19:05 web.1         | [DEBUG]   Menu::Translation Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `menu_translations`.* FROM `menu_translations` WHERE `menu_translations`.`menu_id` IN (8)
14:19:05 web.1         | [DEBUG]   Category Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`name` = 'Registration' LIMIT 1
14:19:05 web.1         | [DEBUG]   OptionalModule Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  `optional_modules`.* FROM `optional_modules`  ORDER BY `optional_modules`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1000
14:19:06 web.1         | [DEBUG]   AdultSetting Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `adult_settings`.* FROM `adult_settings`  ORDER BY `adult_settings`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
14:19:06 web.1         | [DEBUG]   AdultSetting Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `adult_settings`.* FROM `adult_settings`
14:19:06 web.1         | [DEBUG]   AdultSetting::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `adult_setting_translations`.* FROM `adult_setting_translations` WHERE `adult_setting_translations`.`adult_setting_id` = 1
14:19:06 web.1         | [DEBUG]   Slider Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `sliders`.* FROM `sliders` INNER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `sliders`.`category_id` WHERE `sliders`.`online` = 1 AND (categories.name = 'Registration')  ORDER BY `sliders`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
14:19:06 web.1         | [DEBUG]   VideoSetting Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `video_settings`.* FROM `video_settings`  ORDER BY `video_settings`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
14:19:06 web.1         | [DEBUG]    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
14:19:06 web.1         | [DEBUG]   User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'demo22@demo.fr' LIMIT 1
14:19:06 web.1         | [DEBUG]   User Exists (2.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`username` IS NULL AND `users`.`provider` IS NULL) LIMIT 1
14:19:06 web.1         | [DEBUG]   User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`email` = 'demo22@demo.fr' AND `users`.`provider` IS NULL) LIMIT 1
14:19:06 web.1         | [DEBUG]    (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
14:19:06 web.1         | [DEBUG]   OptionalModule Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `optional_modules`.* FROM `optional_modules` WHERE `optional_modules`.`name` = 'SocialConnect' LIMIT 1
14:19:06 web.1         | [DEBUG]   SocialConnectSetting Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `social_connect_settings`.* FROM `social_connect_settings`  ORDER BY `social_connect_settings`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
14:19:06 web.1         | [DEBUG]   SocialProvider Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `social_providers`.* FROM `social_providers` WHERE `social_providers`.`enabled` = 1
14:19:07 web.1         | [INFO ] method=POST path=/admin format=html controller=registrations action=create status=200 duration=1306.84 view=1185.47 db=11.72 unpermitted_params=["username"]
```

here are my development logs for sign_up when it works

```
13:23:23 web.1         | [INFO ] POST    "/admin"  for 127.0.0.1  at 2016-05-14 13:23:23 +0200
13:23:23 web.1         | [DEBUG]   Setting Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `settings`.* FROM `settings`  ORDER BY `settings`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
13:23:23 web.1         | [DEBUG]   Setting::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `setting_translations`.* FROM `setting_translations` WHERE `setting_translations`.`setting_id` = 1
13:23:23 web.1         | [DEBUG]   Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`name` = 'LegalNotice' LIMIT 1
13:23:23 web.1         | [DEBUG]   Menu Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `menus`.* FROM `menus` WHERE `menus`.`id` IN (8)
13:23:23 web.1         | [DEBUG]   Menu::Translation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `menu_translations`.* FROM `menu_translations` WHERE `menu_translations`.`menu_id` IN (8)
13:23:23 web.1         | [DEBUG]   Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`name` = 'Registration' LIMIT 1
13:23:23 web.1         | [DEBUG]   OptionalModule Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `optional_modules`.* FROM `optional_modules`  ORDER BY `optional_modules`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1000
13:23:23 web.1         | [DEBUG]   AdultSetting Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `adult_settings`.* FROM `adult_settings`  ORDER BY `adult_settings`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
13:23:23 web.1         | [DEBUG]   Slider Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `sliders`.* FROM `sliders` INNER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `sliders`.`category_id` WHERE `sliders`.`online` = 1 AND (categories.name = 'Registration')  ORDER BY `sliders`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
13:23:24 web.1         | [DEBUG]   VideoSetting Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `video_settings`.* FROM `video_settings`  ORDER BY `video_settings`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
13:23:24 web.1         | [DEBUG]    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
13:23:24 web.1         | [DEBUG]   User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` IS NOT NULL) AND `users`.`slug` = 'demo18' LIMIT 1
13:23:24 web.1         | [DEBUG]   User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'demo18@demo.fr' LIMIT 1
13:23:24 web.1         | [DEBUG]   User Exists (11.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`username` = 'demo18' AND `users`.`provider` IS NULL) LIMIT 1
13:23:24 web.1         | [DEBUG]   User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`email` = 'demo18@demo.fr' AND `users`.`provider` IS NULL) LIMIT 1
13:23:24 web.1         | [DEBUG]   SQL (4.3ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `encrypted_password`, `username`, `slug`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('demo18@demo.fr', '$2a$10$XzsU01QgfNjK0N.432l5/.UKiSISQ0IhY/kfrQzDrIT476HFnCwVe', 'demo18', 'demo18', '2016-05-14 13:23:24', '2016-05-14 13:23:24')
13:23:24 web.1         | [DEBUG]    (0.5ms)  COMMIT
13:23:24 web.1         | [INFO ] method=POST path=/admin format=html controller=active_admin/devise/registrations action=create status=302 duration=257.00 view=0.00 db=21.08 location=http://rails-starter.dev:3000/admin
```

**My project**:

- Rails 4.2.6
- ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre2
- Devise 3.5.9
- Ruby 2.3.0
- Mac OSX 10.11 (for development)

Comment: Do you intend to create a system where users can have mutiple OAuth authentications tied to a single account? I'm guessing so since you have a provider and username column. In that case you want to use a separate model (and db table) to store the authentication details.

Comment: In my project, Oauth authentication does not allow users to register but only to linked an already existing devise account to a provider. My issue is only when I try to register with a classic devise account. Thanks !

Comment: Do you have a default for the `provider` column? Otherwise you will get issues when the provider field is NULL.

Comment: I don't think the issue come from the provider column as it works sometime. By default, provider is NULL but it's not a problem because I didn't set validation rules for this column. My guess is "configure_permitted_parameters" method is not called (I don't see my logger.debug I put in and my tests breaks) but I don't know why.

Comment: I tried to move the before_action to the ApplicationController directly (I was using a concern) and same thing happened: it works great until I modify just one piece of code and then break again until I killed all ruby processes. Very weird...

Comment: You are running this in the development environment? Do you have anything nonstandard in `config/environments/development.rb` that could explain the issue? A stack trace might be helpful here as well (edit it into the question)

Comment: My development.rb file is very standard. I added to my question logs. I am also facing another issues in the registration process I explained in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147452/how-can-i-override-after-sign-up-path-for-in-activeadmin). I hope it's not conflicting with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111930/discussion-between-max-and-anthony).